# Heroku Local Deploy failed

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am trying to deply the heroku server and run into this error. I included the Procfile.txt in the root folder and inside that text file i have web:npm start

```
$ heroku local web
[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
[WARN] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'Procfile'
[OKAY] package.json file found - trying 'npm start'
9:42:52 PM web.1 |  'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
9:42:52 PM web.1 |  operable program or batch file.
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  SIGINT
9:42:52 PM web.1 Exited with exit code null
```

Comment: Rename `Procfile.txt` to `Procfile`.

Comment: You don't have `npm` installed or it is not in your `PATH`.